# php foreach pass by reference unexpected changes

Tags: php, arrays, reference, foreach

I'm getting crazy about a really weird issue.

This is my source:

```
function load_search_value($meta_query_array) {

    var_dump($meta_query_array);

    foreach($meta_query_array as &$query) {
        // change compare operator to BETWEEN
        $query['compare'] = 'BETWEEN';
    }

    var_dump($meta_query_array);

    return $meta_query_array;
}
```

This is the output from the both calls to `var_dump()` from the above code:

[image: screenshort from var_dump output]

Has anybody an idea what I'm missing?

What the hell can cause the relation operator to change from `AND` to `BND` in the given sourcecode? Am I using the reference operator in a wrong way causing unexpected behaviour?

Comment: why you are using referencing..??`&$query`.?

Comment: Do you have any value named "BND" anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change

```
foreach($meta_query_array as &$query) {
    // change compare operator to BETWEEN
    $query['compare'] = 'BETWEEN';
}
```

with

```
foreach($meta_query_array as $k => &$query) {
    if(is_numeric($k)) {
      // change compare operator to BETWEEN
      $query['compare'] = 'BETWEEN';
    }
}
```

this is because for the first iteration `$k == 'relation'` and `$query == 'AND'`, in this case `$query['compare']` converts to `$query[0]` and the result is that you are changing a letter in the string instead of a value in an array.

Comment: Thank you. I totally forgot that you can access an string using the array syntax, too. ... sometimes you just don't see the obvious. :-)

Comment: @s1lv3r Glad I have been of help =) feel free to accept the answer it it helped you!

Answer (score 4):

The first iteration of foreach returns $query referencing the first array element (`relation`) where you set the `['compare']` value to 'BETWEEN'.... As the 'compare' element doesn't exist, but we have a string that can be addressed by character, we get into loose typing rules, 'compare' == 0, so 0th character is changed to 'B'

Comment: Yep, that is it, as I noticed too.